# How can hitTestObject work for many objects?

Tags: actionscript-3, hittest

I have a game where player moves forward over (semi)random tiles. I want a hittest for when the player hits a certain tile.

However when the char hits one of the spawned in floor2's nothing happens.

**I think this is because there are multiple 'floor2' movieclips on the stage ?**

When i trace the bounds "getBounds" for floor2 the positions it shows keeps changing anyway to Hitest with all of them ?

```
function handleCollision( e:Event ):void {      
if(char.hitTestObject(floor2)){
trace("hit detected");
}
```

This is how the player spawns in:

```
var char:Char = new Char();
char.x = 275;
char.y = 786;
cam.addChild(char);
```

This is how floor2 spawns in :

```
if (randomRounded > 10 && randomRounded <= 50 ){
floor2 = new Floor2();
floor2.x = -8.45;
floor2.y = 786 - tileCounter;
cam.addChildAt(floor2, stage.numChildren-1);
```

Extra : ( RandomRounded is a randomly generated number ), ( there is a 'Var floor2:Floor2;')

**please help :(**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A variable can only ever reference up to one value. So your `floor2` variable can only reference one `Floor2` object. If you assign a new value, the variable will reference that value.

What you should do is to use an `Array`, which can hold many objects.

```
var floors:Array = [];

if (randomRounded > 10 && randomRounded <= 50 ){
    floor2 = new Floor2();
    floor2.x = -8.45;
    floor2.y = 786 - tileCounter;
    cam.addChildAt(floor2, stage.numChildren-1);
    floors.push(floor2); // add the reference to the array, now floor2 can safely be overwritten by a new value without losing the previous one
}
```

In your function `handleCollision` you would then iterate over the array to test each individual floor object. Here's a quick untested example of how that could look like:

```
function handleCollision( e:Event ):void 
{ 
    for (var i:uint = 0; i< floors.length; ++i)
    {     
        if(char.hitTestObject(floors[i]))
        {
            trace("hit detected");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, is there anyway for me to test the whole array in handleCollision not just say floors[2] but all the that is pushed to it

Comment: @Woolff You have to iterate over it, a for loop is one way to do this. Please check my edited answer for an example.